# operador de asignación operación infinita

Tags: c++11

tengo una clase muy simple y estoy implementado mi propio operador de asignación pero el problema viene dentro del condicional, la operación *this = objeto es infinita. Porque pasa esto?

```
 #include <iostream>

class garaje
{
  private:
    unsigned int plazas_garaje;
    unsigned int numero_coches;

  public:
    garaje(unsigned int num_plazas = 0, unsigned int num_coches = 0)
        : plazas_garaje{num_plazas}, numero_coches{num_coches}
    {
    }
    void mostrar()
    {
        std::cout << "plazas de garaje: " << plazas_garaje << "numero de coches en el garaje: " << numero_coches << std::endl;
    }
    garaje(const garaje &object) : plazas_garaje{object.plazas_garaje},
                                   numero_coches{object.numero_coches}
    {
    }

    garaje &operator=(const garaje &object)
    {
        if (this != &object)
        {
            *this = object; // operacion infinita
        }

        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    garaje mi_garaje{1, 2}, mi_garaje2;
    mi_garaje.mostrar();
    mi_garaje2 = mi_garaje;
    mi_garaje.mostrar();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es infinita porque así es exactamente como tú has programado que sea:

```
garaje &operator=( const garaje &object ) {
  if( this != &object ) {
    *this = object; // operacion infinita
  }

  return *this;
}
```

¿ Que hace exactamente `*this = XXX` ? El compilador genera exactamente el mismo código que si hicieras

```
garaje &garaje::operator=( object );
```

Es decir, `*this = object` llama a `operator=( object )`, que a su vez llama a `operator=( object )`, que a su vez llama a `operator=( object )`, ...

Para hacer lo que pretendes, entre las varias opciones disponibles, lo *correcto* es asignar **miembro a miembro**:

```
Garaje &operator=( const Garaje &object ) {
  plazas_garaje = object.plazas_garaje;
  numero_coches = object.numero_coches;

  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El motivo del problema ya te lo han comentado, yo solo expongo una forma alternativa de implementar el operador de asignación:

```
Garaje &operator=( const Garaje &object ) {
  std::tie(plazas_garaje,numero_coches)
   = std::tie(object.plazas_garaje,object.numero_coches);

  return *this;
}
```

La ventaja aquí es que este código sirve para bastantes operadores casi sin cambios, como por ejemplo para los operadores de comparación:

```
bool operator==( const Garaje &object ) {
  return std::tie(plazas_garaje,numero_coches)
      == std::tie(object.plazas_garaje,object.numero_coches);

  return *this;
}

bool operator==( const Garaje &object ) {
  return plazas_garaje == object.plazas_garaje
      && numero_coches == object.numero_coches;
}


bool operator!=( const Garaje &object ) {
  return std::tie(plazas_garaje,numero_coches)
      != std::tie(object.plazas_garaje,object.numero_coches);

}

bool operator!=( const Garaje &object ) {
  return plazas_garaje != object.plazas_garaje
      || numero_coches != object.numero_coches;
}
```